# Element to which Class added dynamically has become unclickable

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox, selector, jsfiddle

I have created a elevator functionality [there are 2 floors and corresponding
to each one , there is a checkbox. Depending upon which checkbox is checked, the elevator
shud move to that floor.

Couple of things which i'm not sure how to implement are:

1. wherever i have added class "unchecked" dynamically, the element looks as if it is not 
   clickable. How do i make it clickable?
2. How to slow down speed of the Orange color elevator when it moves and stops at levels
   where checkbox is checked?

The fiddle is available at : [http://jsfiddle.net/hurricaneankit/rJ4Py/12/]

Comment: Shouldn't it be a radiobutton as it can only be on one floor?  Also, I don't believe animations are possible on the checkmark specifically.  Unless you had your own custom check image somewhere.

Comment: Hexxagonal, could you please have look at the fiddle: 

http://jsfiddle.net/hurricaneankit/rJ4Py/12/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/rJ4Py/34/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#check1, .checked1").click(function () {
        $('.checked1').addClass('fade');
        $('.checked2').removeClass('fade');
        $("#groundDiv").animate({
            "top": "0px"
        }, 2000);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#check2, .checked2").click(function () {
        $('.checked2').addClass('fade');
        $('.checked1').removeClass('fade');
        $("#groundDiv").animate({
            "top": "-65px"
        }, 2000);  
    });
});
```

css-

```
.fade{
    -webkit-animation: fade 3.5s;
    -moz-animation: fade 3.5s;
    -o-animation: fade 3.5s;
    animation: fade 3.5s;
}
@keyframes fade{
    0%{opacity:0;}
    50%{opacity:1;}
    100%{opacity:0;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much apaul34208.... Can u provide me inputs how to make the checkbox get unchecked[sort of fadeout to uncheck state] when the orange elevator has reached that checkbox.

Comment: In the new fiddle, orange elevator is moving up but the checkbox is not getting checked or unchecked.... Please take a look.

Comment: Hi apaul34208... Could u please help me out with this... in your new fiddle, orange elevator is moving up but the checkbox is not getting checked or unchecked

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I added the common browser prefixes to the jsFiddle. Note that the fade effect wont work on older versions of IE, as keyframes aren't supported.